# How to solve (unix:/home/richard/www/firstsite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream)?

Tags: django, nginx, permissions, centos7, uwsgi

I am trying do do this tutorial in a CentOS 7:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7

I want to test a Django basic project with Nginx, uWsgi into a CentOS 7.
But in the browser results this error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.20.1
```

[Error502](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WANoC.jpg)

firstsite.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = firstsite
username = richard
base = /home/%(username)

chdir = %(base)/%(project)/Documentos/desenvolvimento/nginxteste/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

uid = %(username)
socket = /home/richard/www/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

uwsgi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /home/richard/www/; chown richard:nginx /home/richard/www/'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx.conf

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name firstsite.com www.firstsite.com;

        location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/richard/Documentos/desenvolvimento/nginxteste/firstsite;
        }

        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/home/richard/www/firstsite.sock;
        }

    }

  #  server {
   #     listen 80;
   #     server_name secondsite.com www.secondsite.com;
#
 #       location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  #      location /static/ {
   #         root /home/richard/Documentos/desenvolvimento/nginxteste/secondsite;
    #    }
#
 #       location / {
  #          include uwsgi_params;
   #         uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/secondsite.sock;
    #    }
#
 #   }

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Error in /var/log/nginx:

> 2022/05/13 14:03:36 [crit] 53778#53778: *1 connect() to
> unix:/home/richard/www/firstsite.sock failed (13: Permission denied)
> while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.2.139, server:
> firstsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "uwsgi://unix:/home/richard/www/firstsite.sock:", host: "172.17.2.139"

I think its some permission, but I tried everything the error persist.

**Can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by nagvigating to the nginx.conf file
cd /etc/nginx/
then I changed first line "user www-data" to "user root"
NB: "root" was the name of my virtual server